# What is the relevance of this theorem? (Complete orthogonal decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I'm reading the book Matrix Analysis for Scientists and Engineers by Alan J. Laub. In the chapter about Canonical forms, the following theorem is presented:

**Theorem 10.25 (Complete Orthogonal Decomposition)**: *Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_r$. Then there exist unitary matrices $U\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ and $V\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that*
$$UAV=\begin{bmatrix}
R & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

*where $R\in\mathbb{C}^{r\times r}_r$ is upper (or lower) triangular with positive diagonal elements.*

Why is this relevant? It seems like I misunderstood this somehow, since to me this follows immediately from the SVD decomposition of $A$ (explained before in the book), and I expect $R$ to be diagonal, not only triangular. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps finding a triangular (rather than a diagonal) $A$ is computationally easier?  Presumably such a decomposition is non-unique

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I see your point. But then perhaps that makes the algorithm that produces this decomposition interesting, not the theorem itself.

Comment: I think that it is easy to immediately jump to SVD when you see $UAV=\begin{bmatrix}
R & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ since $U$ and $V$ are both unitary. However, SVD says there exists a factorization $A = URV^H$, where $U$ and $H$ are unitary, and $R$ is diagonal, so SVD makes the extra assumption that $R$ is diagonal, while the factorization you are asking makes the assumption that $R$ is triangular. I think it is just another matrix factorization that may or may not come in handy.